# Hibernate ManyToMany update error

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have problem with hibernate and @ManyToMany annotation. Please look at two entities classes:

Company entity:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="company_user_tab",
     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="company_id")},
     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")})
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

... getters and setters
```

User entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="users")
private Set<Company> companies = new HashSet<Company>();

... getters and setters
```

Scenario:
I created first user and first company and connect them correctly.

Problem occured when I create new user and try update existing company with new user. I receive database error on company_user_tab: "duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

It's look like hibernate insert again to join table first user witch is correctly associated with company.

How I update object?

```
entityManager.merge(object);
```

Of course I add before user to company and company to user for example:

```
user.getCompanies().add(company);
company.getUsers().add(user);
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Looks like you haven't set up your cascade properly. Try using `@Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE})` on your sets. That should sort that problem out.

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade= {CaseCadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(
    name = "company_user_tab",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="company_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="user_id") }
)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

// setters and getters
```

Comment: I'm sure that @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL}) will also produce this error. In previos version I checked that option. I don't checked @Nicholas Robinson sugestion